weird svg.getIntersectionList issues
I have that start of a simple handmade diagram app (boxes and arrows) in SVG.  I want to detect overlapping boxes with svgelement.getIntersectionList() - MDN
I am getting a weird result - the getIntersectionList returns a nodeList, but in the top left quadrant of my svg it returns a useful, full list of intersecting nodes; but in the top right, bottom right and bottom left quadrants the nodeList is empty. I think there's a boundary at about 400 units, at which I can sometimes get a useful nodeList from the left-hand box.
My architecture is a board SVG, and nested within it, node SVG containing a rectangle, a ForeignObject and html inside the ForeignObject.  I prefer the nested SVG because the other grouping tag () doesn't have a direct, natural x and y and you would use transform=translate() to achieve the same.
This is the simple example of the element.
<html><head>
     <title>FastHTML page</title>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover">
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@next/dist/htmx.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/answerdotai/fasthtml-js@main/fasthtml.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/answerdotai/surreal@main/surreal.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gnat/css-scope-inline@main/script.js"></script>
   <style>      .htmx-indicator{opacity:0}      .htmx-request .htmx-indicator{opacity:1; transition: opacity 200ms ease-in;}      .htmx-request.htmx-indicator{opacity:1; transition: opacity 200ms ease-in;}      </style></head>
   <body>
     <main>
       <h1>Boxes and Arrows:initial board</h1>
       <div id="brd-1">
         <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1400 700" id="svg-1" class="board" style="border: 1px solid black;">
           <g id="g-nodes">
             <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="101.18749507064152" y="27.593749930150786" hx-post="/board/1/node/1/moved" hx-trigger="nodemoveend" hx-swap="none" id="node-1" class="node draggable selected" hx-vals="{&quot;x&quot;:101.18749507064152, &quot;y&quot;:27.593749930150786, &quot;width&quot;:75, &quot;height&quot;:30}">
               <rect width="75" height="30" x="5" y="5" rx="5" ry="5" id="rect-1"></rect>
               <foreignObject x="5" y="5" height="30" width="75" id="fo-1">
                 <p hx-get="/board/1/node/1/edit" hx-trigger="dblclick" hx-swap="outerHTML" id="p-1" style="color: black">____Node 1</p>
               </foreignObject>
               <circle r="5" cx="80" cy="35" class="resize"></circle>
               <circle r="4" cx="5" cy="20.0" class="connector"></circle>
               <circle r="4" cx="80" cy="20.0" class="connector"></circle>
               <circle r="4" cx="42.5" cy="5" class="connector"></circle>
               <circle r="4" cx="42.5" cy="35" class="connector"></circle>
             </svg>
             <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="67.18749507064152" y="40.593749930150786" hx-post="/board/1/node/2/moved" hx-trigger="nodemoveend" hx-swap="none" id="node-2" class="node draggable selected" hx-vals="{&quot;x&quot;:67.18749507064152, &quot;y&quot;:40.593749930150786, &quot;width&quot;:75, &quot;height&quot;:30}">
               <rect width="75" height="30" x="5" y="5" rx="5" ry="5" id="rect-2"></rect>
               <foreignObject x="5" y="5" height="30" width="75" id="fo-2">
                 <p hx-get="/board/1/node/2/edit" hx-trigger="dblclick" hx-swap="outerHTML" id="p-2" style="color: black">____Node 2</p>
               </foreignObject>
               <circle r="5" cx="80" cy="35" class="resize"></circle>
               <circle r="4" cx="5" cy="20.0" class="connector"></circle>
               <circle r="4" cx="80" cy="20.0" class="connector"></circle>
               <circle r="4" cx="42.5" cy="5" class="connector"></circle>
               <circle r="4" cx="42.5" cy="35" class="connector"></circle>
             </svg>
           </g>
           <g id="g-edges"></g>
           <script>"use strict";

// Get the SVG element and all the "g" elements (nodes)
const svgElement = document.querySelector('svg.board');
const viewBox = svgElement.getAttribute('viewBox').split(' ').map(Number);
const min_x = viewBox[0];
const min_y = viewBox[1];
const max_x = viewBox[2]-100;
const max_y = viewBox[3]-50;

let x1;
let y1;
let x2;
let y2;
let dx;
let dy;

let nodes = document.querySelectorAll('svg.node.draggable');
nodes.forEach((node) =&gt; {
    node.space = svgElement.createSVGRect()
    node.space.x = node.getAttribute("x");
    node.space.y = node.getAttribute("y");
    node.space.height = node.getAttribute("height");
    node.space.width = node.getAttribute("width");
});
// Add event listeners to the SVG element

let selectedElement = null;
let relatedElements = null;
let relatedEdges = null;
let offset;

svgElement.addEventListener('mousedown', handleMousedown);
svgElement.addEventListener('mouseleave', handleMouseup);

document.addEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseup);
document.addEventListener('mouseleave', handleMouseup);

const nodemovestart = new CustomEvent("nodemovestart", {bubbles: true, cancelable: true});
const nodemoveend = new CustomEvent("nodemoveend", {bubbles: true, cancelable: true});

let sharedmove = new CustomEvent("sharedmove", {detail: {"dx":dx, "dy":dy}})

const noderesizestart = new CustomEvent("noderesizestart", {bubbles: true, cancelable: true});
const noderesizeend = new CustomEvent("noderesizeend", {bubbles: true, cancelable: true});

const nodeconnectstart = new CustomEvent("nodeconnectstart", {bubbles: true, cancelable: true});
const nodeconnectend = new CustomEvent("nodeconnectend", {bubbles: true, cancelable: true});
const nodeconnectalt = new CustomEvent("nodeconnectalt", {bubbles: true, cancelable: true});

const selectnode = new CustomEvent("selectnode", {bubbles: true, cancelable: true});
const deselectnode = new CustomEvent("deselectnode", {bubbles: true, cancelable: true});
function handleNodeMoveStart(event) {
    svgElement.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMousemove);
    console.log("--handleNodeMoveStart");
}
function handleNodeMoveEnd(event) {
    svgElement.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMousemove);
    console.log("--handleNodeMoveEnd");
    }
function handleResizeStart(event) {
console.log("--handleResizeStart");
}
function handleResizeEnd(event) {
console.log("--handleResizeEnd");
}

function handleConnectStart(event){
       console.log("--handleConnectStart");
}

function handleConnectEnd(event) {
        console.log("--handleConnectEnd");

}

function handleNodeConnectAlt(event) {
        console.log("--handleNodeConnectAlt");
    // alt nodeclick

}

function handleSelectNode(event) {
    // Shift + click on a .node object
    // Shift-click to select/deselect nodes
    console.log("--SelectNode");
    let targetNode = event.target;
    console.log("handleSelectNode", targetNode);
    if (targetNode.classList.contains('selected')) {
                targetNode.classList.remove('selected');
    } else {
                targetNode.classList.add('selected');
    }
    relatedElements = document.querySelectorAll('.selected');
}

function handleDeselectNode(event) {
    console.log("--DeSelectNode");
    let selectedNodes =Array.from(svgElement.querySelectorAll('.selected'));
    selectedNodes.forEach(node =&gt; {
                node.classList.remove('selected');
            });
}

svgElement.addEventListener("nodemovestart", handleNodeMoveStart);
svgElement.addEventListener("nodemoveend", handleNodeMoveEnd);
svgElement.addEventListener("noderesizestart", handleResizeStart);
svgElement.addEventListener("noderesizeend", handleResizeEnd);
svgElement.addEventListener("nodeconnectstart", handleConnectStart);
svgElement.addEventListener("nodeconnectend", handleConnectEnd);
svgElement.addEventListener("nodeconnectalt", handleNodeConnectAlt);
svgElement.addEventListener("selectnode", handleSelectNode);
svgElement.addEventListener("deselectnode", handleDeselectNode);

function getMousePosition(evt) {
  var CTM = svgElement.getScreenCTM();
  return {
    x: (evt.clientX - CTM.e) / CTM.a,
    y: (evt.clientY - CTM.f) / CTM.d
  };
}

function setOffset(event, element, x_pos_name, y_pos_name) {
        offset = getMousePosition(event);
        offset.x -= parseFloat(element.getAttribute(x_pos_name));
        offset.y -= parseFloat(element.getAttribute(y_pos_name));
}


function handleMousedown(event) {
    // Check if the event originated within a "g" element (node)
    let targetNode;
    if (event.target.classList.contains('resize')) {
        targetNode = event.target;
        console.log("resize", targetNode);
        setOffset(event, targetNode, "cx", "cy");
        targetNode.dispatchEvent(noderesizestart);
    } else if (event.target.classList.contains('connector')) {
        targetNode = event.target;
        console.log("connector", targetNode);
        setOffset(event, targetNode, "cx", "cy");
        targetNode.dispatchEvent(nodeconnectstart);
    } else if (event.target.classList.contains('vicinity')) { // do nothing
        event.preventDefault();
    } else if (event.shiftKey) {
        targetNode = event.target.closest("svg.node");
        console.log("shift - select", targetNode);
        targetNode.dispatchEvent(selectnode);
    } else if (event.altKey) {
        targetNode = event.target.closest("svg.node");
        console.log("alt - select", targetNode);
        targetNode.dispatchEvent(nodeconnectalt);
    }
    else  {
        console.log("movestart target", event.target);
        targetNode = event.target.closest("svg.node");
        if (targetNode) {
            // console.log("nodemovestart", targetNode)
            selectedElement = targetNode;
            setOffset(event, targetNode, "x", "y");
            targetNode.dispatchEvent(nodemovestart);
            if (targetNode.classList.contains('selected')) {
                relatedElements = svgElement.querySelectorAll('svg.node.selected');
            }}
        }
    if (event.target.classList.contains('board')) {
        // console.log("clicked board, deselect selections");
        svgElement.dispatchEvent(deselectnode);
    }
}
function handleMousemove(event) {
    if (event.shiftKey || event.altKey) {
        // probably some valid interpretation of this exists - e.g. select boxes
        // but for now these are click selections and any mousemove during a click is ignored
    }
    else if (selectedElement) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // Convert screen coordinates to SVG coordinates
    let coord = getMousePosition(event);
    x1 = parseFloat(selectedElement.getAttribute("x"));
    y1 = parseFloat(selectedElement.getAttribute("y"));
    x2 = (coord.x - offset.x);
    y2 = (coord.y - offset.y);
    dx = x2 - x1;
    dy = y2 - y1;
    // seems like invoking the constructor for every instance can't be right
    // svgElement.dispatchEvent(sharedmove);

    if (relatedElements) {
        relatedElements.forEach((node) =&gt; {
              let node_x2 = parseFloat(node.getAttribute("x")) + dx;
              let node_y2 = parseFloat(node.getAttribute("y")) + dy;
              // apply board travel limits (subtract width and height)
              node_x2 = ((min_x &lt;= node_x2) &amp;&amp; (node_x2 &lt;= max_x)) ? node_x2 : ((min_x &gt;= node_x2) ? min_x : max_x);
              node_y2 = ((min_y &lt;= node_y2) &amp;&amp; (node_y2 &lt;= max_y)) ? node_y2 : ((min_y &gt;= node_y2) ? min_y : max_y);
              node.setAttribute("x", node_x2);
              node.setAttribute("y", node_y2);
        })
    }
    else {
        selectedElement.setAttribute("x", x2);
        selectedElement.setAttribute("y", y2);}
    }
}

function set_node_hx_vals (node) {
    let x = node.getAttribute("x");
    let y = node.getAttribute("y");
    let width = node.getElementsByTagName("rect")[0].getAttribute("width");
    let height = node.getElementsByTagName("rect")[0].getAttribute("height");
    node.setAttributeNS(null, "hx-vals",
        `{"x":${x}, "y":${y}, "width":${width}, "height":${height}}`

    );
    return node.getAttribute("hx-vals");
}

function handleMouseup(event) {
    if (event.shiftKey || event.altKey) {
    }
    else if (relatedElements) {
        relatedElements.forEach((node) =&gt; {
            set_node_hx_vals(node);
            if (node === selectedElement) {
            } else {
                node.dispatchEvent(nodemoveend);
            }
            relatedElements = null;
        });
    }
    if (selectedElement) {
        set_node_hx_vals(selectedElement);
        selectedElement.dispatchEvent(nodemoveend);
    }
    selectedElement = null;
    relatedEdges = null;
}
/* Intersection Observer not a solution for svgs in svgs
*  getIntersectionList
*
* */


function getSVGboundBox(element) {
    var CTM = svgElement.getScreenCTM();
    let r = svgElement.createSVGRect();
    r.x = Math.round(Number(element.getAttribute("x")));
    r.y = Math.round(Number(element.getAttribute("y")));
    r.width = Math.round(Number(element.getElementsByTagName("rect")[0].getAttribute("width")));
    r.height = Math.round(Number(element.getElementsByTagName("rect")[0].getAttribute("height")));

    // let rect = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'rect');
    // rect.setAttribute("x", r.x);
    // rect.setAttribute("y", r.y);
    // rect.setAttribute("height", r.height+10);
    // rect.setAttribute("width", r.width+10);
    // rect.setAttribute("stroke", "red");
    // rect.setAttribute("class", "getIntersectionBox");
    // svgElement.getElementById("g-nodes").appendChild(rect);
    return r
}
function check_overlaps() {
    nodes.forEach((node) =&gt; {
        console.log("getIntersectionList", node, svgElement.getIntersectionList(getSVGboundBox(node), null));
    })
}

check_overlaps();
</script>
           <style>/* Basic node styling */
.node {
    fill: lightgray; /* Or any other base color you prefer */
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 2;
    /* cursor: pointer; /* Indicate that the node is interactive */
    transition: all 0.2s ease; /* Smooth transitions for visual effects */

}

.static {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
.draggable {
  cursor: move;
}

rect {
    opacity: 0.2;
}

circle.resize {
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: move;
}

circle.resize:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

circle.connector {
    opacity: 0;
}

circle.connector:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
}

p {
    user-select: none;
    color: black;
}

input {
    align-self: center;
}

foreignObject {
    align-items: center;
}

.vicinity {
    opacity: 0.05;
    overflow: visible;
}

/* Styling for selected nodes */
.node.selected {
    fill: #4CAF50; /* Green color for selected nodes */
    stroke: #333; /* Darker stroke for better contrast */
    stroke-width: 3;
    transform: scale(1.1); /* Slightly enlarge selected nodes */
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); /* Subtle shadow for depth */
}

rect.getIntersectionBox {
    border: #BB2255;
    opacity: 0.0;
}

rect.getIntersectionBox:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;

}
.node.arrowFrom {
    fill: #BB2255; /* Green color for selected nodes */
    stroke: #333; /* Darker stroke for better contrast */
    stroke-width: 3;
    transform: scale(1.1); /* Slightly enlarge selected nodes */
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); /* Subtle shadow for depth */
}
.node.arrowTo{
    fill: #5522FF; /* Green color for selected nodes */
    stroke: #333; /* Darker stroke for better contrast */
    stroke-width: 3;
    transform: scale(1.1); /* Slightly enlarge selected nodes */
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); /* Subtle shadow for depth */
}


/* Hover effect for nodes (optional) */
.node:hover {
    stroke: #555;
    stroke-width: 4.0;
}</style>
         </svg>
       </div>
     </main>
</body></html>
  

I've tried visualising the output of my getSVGboundBox with a  element and each one covers the box SVG correctly.  As discussed above, I tried the overlapping nodes in different locations on the main svg board and got different results from "check_overlaps()" - it works in the top left corner and doesn't detect overlaps otherwise.  I looked into "IntersectionObserver" but I don't think they are built for SVG elements.

Frankly I'm not surprised as getIntersectionList() has a quite wobbly browser support. Nested svgs as well as foreignObjects are also prone to errors. Please, provide a running snippet to illustrate the problem/desired result better.

yes I thought the svg and foreignObject might cause problems (e.g SVG.getBBox called on an svg returns values of contained entities in the nested-svg coordinates, so always 0,0.).  Thanks for the link to the polyfill; will try that out.

Thanks for updating the code. Unfortunately, it has quite a few errors (e.g escaped arrows =>  and > entities. If the elements you're checking for intersections are rectangles you should be able to do a simple bbox test as described here "Intersection of 2 SVG Paths"
